# 3 Column ListBox in Silverlight for Wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm really going mad ... but the whole evening I'm trying to create a 3 column listbox. I want that the 3 columns are spread over the whole size of the listbox and not sticked together like they do when using the code below.

So, here's my XML

```
<ListBox Background="Red" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"
         >

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Aquamarine">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="A"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="B"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="C"/>
            </Grid>        
        </DataTemplate>            
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I found a solution:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/d93281f3-d369-45b9-ae50-ce273941f959

Comment: we dont have access to the link. Please avoid linking to other sources, your answer should be an answer, not a link. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `Width` attribute of a `ColumnDefinition` to `Auto` that column will only use the minimum required width. Change the width of all 3 columns to `*`.

Also try setting the `HorizontalAlignment` attribute of the 3 `TextBlock`s to `Center`.